# Window size small on iPhone 5/6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout

I have having ass issue with an iOS8 app, I use auto layout but not size classes in my storyboard. My app works as expected in iPhone 4s and on iPhone 6+ but when viewed on an iPhone 5/5S/6 the window seems to be the wrong size, I get a black border at the top and bottom of the screen. I have attached a screenshot below. What could cause this? I have never encountered it before..[image]

Comment: You are missing the correct size of launch screen for 4" and 4.7" devies. If you have them in your project make sure they are in the list of launch screen in te info.plist. If you are using image assets make sure they are present in the `LaunchImage` section.

Comment: That would be silly let me investigate!

Comment: This was exactly the issue, i added a LaunchScreen instead and removed the asset catalogue for the launch images. Worked a treat. Had no idea launch images could do this. Much appreciated! If you add this as an answer i will accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the correct size of launch screen for 4" and 4.7" devies. If you have them in your project make sure they are in the list of launch screen in te info.plist. If you are using image assets make sure they are present in the `LaunchImage` section.